# Search word in txt file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a txt file and with PHP i need to get email1@gmail.com and email2@gmail.com How can i do it?

I have 2 days searching the solution but i dont find it.

I try this but don't work:

```html
    $filedata = file_get_contents("file.txt");
preg_match_all('~^Email:(.*)$~m', $filedata, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $clave=>$result_email)
        {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, email, pass FROM table_bd WHERE email=? ")) {
  
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $result_email);
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows ==1) {
                // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $pass);
        $stmt->fetch();
        }
         }
       echo $name.":".$pass."<br/>";
    }
```

I have this txt file:

```
#name,email/username,password,description,unique name,email validation username
"lyndia.easda,geasdsadrs,,234342:4344,rocasda34,TasdadL,,01/01/1900,""" 
Username:user1

Biography:  

UserId:6333 

Email:email1@gmail.com  

PhoneNumber:+82234614   

"Original number::325 /5ersion/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25"""
"asdasd.985,asd34e3,,456465:6573,rocsdad7,023sa,,01/01/1900,""" 
Username:user2  
    Biography:  

UserId:392347703    

Email:email2@gmail.com  

PhoneNumber:+823werrs
```

Comment: In what way does your current code not work? What is the result of running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`strpos()`](https://php.net/strpos) returns `FALSE` or `0`. It's different : `FALSE` if not found, `0` at index 0.

You have to use a [strict equality](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to check if it is false or 0 :

```
if (strpos($line, $word) !== false)
```

Will outputs :

```
Word find: Email: 8

Word find: Email: 19
```

---

Another way to get email:

```
$filedata = file_get_contents("file.txt");
preg_match_all('~^Email:(.*)$~m', $filedata, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => example1@gmail.com
    [1] => example2@gmail.com
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but DON'T WORK :(! I have 0 result

Comment: @Dragonasu I've updated the answer with full code. This code is tested and works as expected. Could you try it please?

Comment: Don't Work. I try with $word=":"; and $word="a";  $word="1"; and i find results, but when i put 2 character or more dont work! I receive 0 results

Comment: I need to get the email, only this i need. I need to get the email have in txt file, example: email1@gmail.com, email2@gmail.com

Comment: Thank you its working But only i have 1 result. I need all emails

Comment: One more question, how can i connect the mysql with the result of emails@gmail.com?  I updated the question.

Comment: I create this post, thank your for you time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225115/do-a-mysql-select-in-foreach-with-php

Comment: @Dragonasu Ok :) Thank you too. So please, rollback your question to original version ;) I'll have a look to your new one.

Comment: Thank you, look the post. I need to get a result with mysql SELECT, but when i put the result of the foreach don't give me the select. Give a error

Comment: @Dragonasu Please! [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49222409/revisions) and use the _"rollback"_ link on the version 2, to keep the answer consistent with the accepted answer. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get Email value as

```
if (strpos($line, $word) !== false) {
  $email_array = explode(":",fgets($line));
  $email_array[1];//this will give you email id
  echo "<p>Word find: <b> $email_array[1]</b></p>";
  echo $line_count;
}
```