# Do a Mysql Select in Foreach with PHP

Tags: php

I have a txt file and with PHP i get email1@gmail.com and email2@gmail.com...
When i get the emails with foreach i need to insert a stmt Select. But don't work. How can i resolve?

```
    $filedata = file_get_contents("file.txt");
preg_match_all('~^Email:(.*)$~m', $filedata, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $clave=>$result_email)
        {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, email, pass FROM table_bd WHERE email=? ")) {

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $result_email);
        $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows ==1) {
                // get variables from result.
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $pass);
        $stmt->fetch();
        }
         }
       echo $name.":".$pass."<br/>";
    }
```

Txt file:

```
#name,email/username,password,description,unique name,email validation username
"lyndia.easda,geasdsadrs,,234342:4344,rocasda34,TasdadL,,01/01/1900,""" 
Username:user1

Biography:  

UserId:6333 

Email:email1@gmail.com  

PhoneNumber:+82234614   

"Original number::325 /5ersion/6.0 Mobile/10B350 Safari/8536.25"""
"asdasd.985,asd34e3,,456465:6573,rocsdad7,023sa,,01/01/1900,""" 
Username:user2  
    Biography:  

UserId:392347703    

Email:email2@gmail.com  

PhoneNumber:+823werrs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper Syntax for what you're trying to do is:

```
$filedata = file_get_contents("file.txt");
preg_match_all('~^Email:(.*)$~m', $filedata, $matches);

foreach ($matches as $result_email)
{
    $sql = "SELECT name, email, pass FROM table_bd WHERE email=?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $result_email[1]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows ==1) {
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $email, $pass);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            echo $name.":".$pass."<br/>";
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Unless you store the resultset the variables $name, $email, and $pass don't persist outside of the fetch function.

Comment: THank you but its not working :( I have the error here:         if ($stmt->num_rows ==1) {

Comment: Editing to accommodate your numrows check, statements need to be stored for that to work my fault.  :)

Comment: I have 0 results, i try to put the email manual in the select and its finding. When i try with the $result_email values give me 0 results.

Comment: Try using $stmt->bind_param('s', $clave=>result_email);  or better yet store your for loop as ($matches[1] as $result_email) in the first place.

Comment: I know what is the error! I try it to get the value of email with this (            echo "+".$result_email."+";) and i obtain: +email1@gmail.com +, how can i remove the space ?

Comment: $result_email = str_replace(" ", "", $result_email); will work assuming you'll never want spaces in an email regardless.

Comment: @Dragonasu Or maybe juste change the regexp to : `'~^Email:([^\s]+)$~m'`.

Comment: True but having not seen his data model I have no idea where \ why he's getting extra padding in his results.  Your regex is a better idea but I'm on my phone ATM so I went the easy route :)

Comment: Thank you @MasonStedman and Syscall i resolve with trim($result_email). The problem was in the space! Thank you very much!